# Eclipse invalid configuration location

Tags: eclipse

I was working fine with Eclipse for about a week but suddenly now when I start the eclipse, I get the following error:

```
invalid configuration location
The configuration area at ---'/home/yash/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration' is not writable.  
Please choose a writable location using the '-configuration' command line option.
```

Please help.

Comment: From terminal, execute "ls -al /home/yash/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration" and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting yourself as the owner of the config-directory:

`sudo chown -R yash:yash ~/.eclipse`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a multiuser enviroment ?? the problem can be resolved by root previliged terminal and executing following commands

```
cd /usr/share
chown -R root:root eclipse
chmod -R g-w eclipse
```

read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/665454/#msg_665454) for more information